# Switching OpenJDK via atlernatives to java-1.8.0-openjdk failed! /usr/bin may not exists or point to different java version

Tags: java, bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting following error if i select freestyle project and cant execute bash scripts:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Checking OpenJDK installation...
$ rpm -q java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64
Checking OpenJDK installation...
$ rpm -q java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64
Switching to java-1.8.0-openjdk using alternatives ... 
$ sudo alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java has not been configured as an alternative for java
[OpenJDK ERROR] Switching OpenJDK via atlernatives to java-1.8.0-openjdk failed! /usr/bin may not exists or point to different java version!
```

JAVA_HOME at configure system is:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the symbolic link `/usr/bin/java` and then relaunch `sudo alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the `openJDK-native-plugin`. So I had to uninstall it completely.